# Unsatisfied dependency running a Test in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, junit4

I've generated a Spring Boot web application using Spring Initializr, using embedded Tomcat + Thymeleaf template engine, and package as an executable JAR file.

Technologies used :

Spring Boot 1.4.2.RELEASE, Spring 4.3.4.RELEASE, Thymeleaf 2.1.5.RELEASE, Tomcat Embed 8.5.6, Maven 3, Java 8

I have this test:

```
    @ContextConfiguration(classes={PersistenceConfig.class})
    @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
    public class BooksManagerTests {

        /**
         * The object being tested.
         */
        @Autowired
        BooksManager booksManager;


        @Test
        public void testfindDeviceByKey() {
                            booksManager.findDeviceByKey("C380F");
        }
    }


    @Configuration
    public class PersistenceConfig {

        @Bean
        public  JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate() {
            return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource());
        }


        @Bean 
        public BooksManager booksManager() {
            return new BooksManagerImpl();
        }

        /**
         * Creates an in-memory "rewards" database populated 
         * with test data for fast testing
         */
        @Bean
        public DataSource dataSource(){
            return
                (new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder())
                .addScript("classpath:db/H2.schema.sql")
                .addScript("classpath:db/H2.data.sql")
                .build();
        }

    }


    @Service("booksManager")
    public class BooksManagerImpl implements BooksManager {


        private DeviceEventRepository deviceEventRepository;

        @Autowired
        public void setDeviceEventRepository(DeviceEventRepository   deviceEventRepository) {
            this.deviceEventRepository = deviceEventRepository;
        }

        @Override
        public List<DeviceEvent> getAllDeviceEvents() {
            return deviceEventRepository.getAllDeviceEvents();
        }
    }


@Repository("deviceEventRepository")
public class JdbcDeviceEventRepository implements DeviceEventRepository {

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;


    @Override
    public List<DeviceEvent> getAllDeviceEvents() {
        String sql = "select * from t_device_event";
        return mapDeviceEvents(jdbcTemplate.queryForList(sql));
    }

    private List<DeviceEvent> mapDeviceEvents(List<Map<String,Object>> deviceEventsMap) {
        return null;
    }


}
```

but I got this error running the test:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'booksManager': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setDeviceEventRepository' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.tdk.repository.DeviceEventRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved adding this to PersistenceConfig class

```
@Bean 
    public DeviceEventRepository deviceEventRepository() {
        return new JdbcDeviceEventRepository();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your application only specifies a single configuration during initialization:

> @ContextConfiguration(classes={PersistenceConfig.class})

You need to start your application by specifying a main like this to enable Spring boot auto-configuration:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
  }
```

}

See [JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/jpa/JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration.html) for more information on JPA Repositories auto-configuration.